# How can I access the fields of an interface in Go?

Tags: go, struct, interface

I'm trying to do this:

```
if event.Type == sdl.QUIT {
    utils.Running = false
}
```

But I can't because when I try to build, I get this error:

```
 ./mm.go:11: event.Type undefined (type sdl.Event has no field or method Type)
```

Here is the relevant source code of the library I'm trying to use:

```
type Event interface{}    

type CEvent struct {
    Type uint32
    _    [52]byte // padding
}

type CommonEvent struct {
    Type      uint32
    Timestamp uint32
}

// WindowEvent (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent)
type WindowEvent struct {
    Type      uint32
    Timestamp uint32
    WindowID  uint32
    Event     uint8
    _         uint8 // padding
    _         uint8 // padding
    _         uint8 // padding
    Data1     int32
    Data2     int32
}
```

As you can see, all of the other Events have the field `Type`. How can I access this?

## Solution

This how I ended up polling events in [this SDL2 binding for Go](https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/), in case anyone is wondering:

```
func PollEvents() {
    for {
        if event := sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil {
            switch event.(type) {
            case *sdl.QuitEvent:
                utils.Running = false
            }
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can't. Interfaces only define a method set that is available on a type, they do nothing to expose fields. In your case I would recommend doing a type switch. It would look a little like this;

```
     switch v := myInstance.(type) {
                case CEvent:
                        fmt.Println(v)
                case CommonEvent:
                        fmt.Println(v)
                case WindowEvent:
                        fmt.Println(v)
                default:
                        fmt.Println("unknown")
        }
```

You may want to structure your code a bit differently depending on what you're doing with the instance after this but that gives you the basic idea. You can also do a type assertion with a single type like; `v, err := myInstance.(CommonEvent)` but I doubt it would be as effective here. It also returns an error if the type of `myInstance` is not `CommonEvent` so it's not really the best way to go about figuring out what type and interface instance may be.

Comment: I'm fairly new to go, but I don't know that this way is possible? http://play.golang.org/p/2cxLDoabfs

Comment: @william.taylor.09 it works fine, your example correctly produces 'unknown' because you're passing a `*WindowEvent` - which is not the same type as a `WindowEvent` and there is no case for it. Here's a modified example that does what you'd expect; http://play.golang.org/p/ZEkf3tKI53

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm getting really annoying `variable declared but not used` error at compile time if I don't use `v`. I don't want to use `v` aside from each `case SomeEvent:` line. Is there anyway to get around having to using it?

Comment: @gragas I'd have to see the rest of your code but my guess would be that you're declaring `v` above the switch, rather than making declaration and assignment part of switch statement like in the example above. If `v` is declared in the switch statement like in the example above then it's scope is limited to the switch statement so you shouldn't have to use it anywhere but in the case statements.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'm running essentially your example, except I don't use `v` inside any of the cases. Because once I know the type of the event, I don't need to use it. Could this be a golang bug? Here's a gist of my code that causes this problem: https://gist.github.com/gragas/696a16cbc6bd2cee201d82f75c12fbb6

Comment: @gragas ah I see. Nah, you just write the switch without any assignment. Since there is a variable declared in that example, it must be used in order to be valid Go. But, if you just care to know the type of the variable and don't actually need to do anything with it then you can write it like this; http://play.golang.org/p/RaClQUWn-O

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Ah that makes sense.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal This still does not allow me to access the field `Type`. I don't really care about the `type` of the object in Golang. I just want to know the value of the first field (which happens to have the name `Type`).

Comment: @gragas you have to assign `v` in order to access fields on that type. Look at my first example in the comments (http://play.golang.org/p/ZEkf3tKI53) it prints the value of `v.Type`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the type. Let's say we know it's a CEvent:

```
cEvent, ok := Event.(CEvent)
if !ok {
    // You lied, not a CEvent
    return
}

// Otherwise, you can get the type!
fmt.Println(cEvent.Type)
```

Of course if you *don't* know the type, you can keep type asserting until you get it right. Otherwise, throw an error, return a default value, etc:

```
func getType(i interface{}) uint32 {
    cEvent, ok := i.(CEvent)
    if ok {
        return cEvent.Type
    }

    commonEvent, ok := i.(CommonEvent)
    if ok {
        return commonEvent.Type
    }

    // Etc

    return <default>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can spend a lot of time doing reflection calls or trying to guess the type or using type switches.

Or you can just define an interface with functions that return the information you need.

For example you could do

```
type Event interface {
    GetCommonEvent() *CommonEvent
    GetWindowEvent() *WindowEvent
}
```